# Swap first two characters, then next two characters in a String using Java

Tags: java, string

I have been trying this program for a while now but not able to get a right solution to it. For example, the input is `123456`, which is entered by the user. I want to swap the first two characters, then the next two and so on. So, the output should be `214365`. I have tried the following code but not able to get the desired output.

```
public static void main(String[] arg$) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a word: ");
    String str = in.nextLine();

    char[] arr = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char temp1, temp2;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        try {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                temp2 = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp2;
            } else {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                temp1 = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i+2];
                arr[i + 2] = temp1;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    System.out.println("The final String is : =\n\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
}
```

> Sample Input:
>
> 123456
>
> Sample Output:
>
> 213456

Comment: Could you [edit] your post and include some sample input and output?

Comment: Actually I meant sample input/output that you are getting, not what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are swapping the first character with the second, and then the second with the third, and so on. That's not what you are supposed to do.

There should be at most n/2 swaps for a String of n characters (the number of swaps will be smaller than n/2 if n is odd).

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
    if (i + 1 < arr.length) {
        temp2 = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to swap every other character, I would start with a `StringBuilder` and a method to swap any two character(s) at given positions. Something like,

```
static void swap(StringBuilder sb, int a, int b) {
    if (a != b && a < sb.length() && b < sb.length()) {
        char ch = sb.charAt(a);
        sb.setCharAt(a, sb.charAt(b));
        sb.setCharAt(b, ch);
    }
}
```

Then you could invoke it in a simple `for` loop. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a word: ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i += 2) {
        swap(sb, i, i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Which I ran with your provided input (and got your expected output). Specifically,

```
enter a word: 
123456
214365
```